# How do i make instance for array of ToolStripMenuItem items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In top of form1:

```
ToolStripMenuItem[] items;
```

In constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    items[i] = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(items);
}

if (!File.Exists(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt"))
{
    recentfiles = new StreamWriter(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt");
    recentfiles.Close();
}
else
{
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt");
}
```

Before it i used single item and i made one instance for it in the top of form1.
But i want to add to the DropDownItems array of items. And i don't how many items i want for it to be unlimited.

Then i have this event:

```
private void recentFilesToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        items[i].Text = lines[i];
    }            
}
```

When i used a single item i just did in the MouseEnter event:

```
item.Text = "hello world";
```

But now i want to add the items from the text file it can be 1 items or 200 items the problem is that items are null in the constructor.

I did now in the constructor changed it to:

```
if (!File.Exists(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt"))
{
    recentfiles = new StreamWriter(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt");
    recentfiles.Close();
}
else
{
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt");
    items = new ToolStripMenuItem[lines.Length];
}
```

In this case lines.Length is 3.
But now when i look on items i see 3 items that each one of them is null.
So i know how many items i need to instance but for some reason they are all null.

Comment: So... are you having trouble initialising the array? Also sounds like you need a `List<T>` initially because you don't know how many items you are going to add?

Comment: If you don't know in advance the number of items you are going to need, then an array is not a good choice. use a `List<ToolStripMenuItem>` instead.

Comment: I changed it. I know how many items to add after reading the lines from the text file. Updated my question.

Comment: @SimonGamlieli Can you update the question to post the complete code for the constructor? It looks like they are null because you are initialising the array itself, but not then putting anything into the elements of that array.

Comment: Instantiating the array like this does not instantiate it's members automatically. You will still need the loop to instantiate every member of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that your *main problem* is in the fact that you don't know in advance the *length* of `items[]`; such problem is a good task for *Linq*, something like that:

```
  private ToolStripMenuItem[] items;

  ...
```

in the constructor:

```
  items = File
    .ReadLines(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt")
    .Select(line => new ToolStripMenuItem() {
       Text = line
     })
    .ToArray();
  ...
  // if items are used in AddRange only
  // you have no need neither of ToArray() nor in private field
  recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(items);
```

in case you want, say, 10 first recent files only:

```
  items = File
    .ReadLines(@"e:\RecentFiles.txt")
    .Take(10)
    .Select(line => new ToolStripMenuItem() {
       Text = line
     })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Dmitry the instance is working. And then how do i add the items to the ecentFilesToolStripMenuItem in the MouseEnter event like in my question ? The loop i'm doing in the event is'n adding the items. When i did single item like item.Text = "hell world"; it was working in the event but now it's not.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, for `MouseEnte` it could be the similar *Linq query*: read and (if necessary filter out) the lines, create `ToolStripMenuItem`s from them and, finally, add ietms to `recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItem` via `AddRange`.